# Application Error when logging in with JavaScript SDK, using oauth opt in login

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here is my code:

```
FB.init({
    appId  : this.api_id,
    status : true,
    cookie : true,
    xfbml  : true,
    oauth  : true,
    channelUrl  : 'https://blah.com/facebook/channel'  // custom channel
});
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        if (response.perms) {
        // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
        if(typeof redirect === 'function') {
            redirect();
        }else {
            window.location = redirect;
            }
        } else {
        // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
        }
    } else {
        // user is not logged in
    }
},{
        scope: 'email'
}
);
```

So what happens is that if i have oauth no set in FB.init everything works fine but if i add in 
oauth is true then i will get back

```
<span>Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later. </span>
```

from the request to /dialog/oauth

I followed all the roadmap to oauth 2 here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/
and still no luck, something seems a bit off here.

And no all the code posted in not all the code i have, before FB.login gets called i make sure
FB.init has already been called. Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check if your application is in sandbox mode. If it is, switch sandbox mode off and try again.
  If sandbox mode is on FB will not recognize your app and a call to Facebook.init will fail silently, when you are not logged in, returning the response 'Application Error: There was a problem getting data for the application you requested. The application may not be valid, or there may be a temporary glitch. Please try again later.'